# How to get div width from within an iframe? Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, height

How would I go about getting the height of a div within an iframe. Right now I am using jquery, and document ready. Here's the code I have right now.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log($(".cf_offers").height());  
});
```

The div of the iframe is content_iframe, but is it needed? Because the div has the width when the page is ready. But it just outputs null.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the contents in that Div getting loaded dynamically.?

Comment: It's getting loaded in an iframe from a php file on my server. If that's what you meant.

Comment: Try to get its height inside `$('.cf_offers').load(function(){ })`

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't output anything now.

Comment: I managed to calculate the height with PHP, because every 'tr' was 49px in the height, and then I just multiplied the offers count with 49. But thanks to both of you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not violating the same-origin policy, you have to use `contents()` to get the contents of the iFrame and find elements etc.

The iFrame would have to be loaded, but if that's not an issue, you can remove the onload handler :

```
$("#content_iframe").on('load', function() {
    var width = $(this).contents().find(".cf_offers").height();
});
```

Comment: Tried to console.log the width, but it doesn't return anything. Do you know why? Could it be that the iframe is hidden in a 'modal' a popup modal.